# Error when clicking textView in table row

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a table row which contains textviews 
I am trying to use intents to click on the text view to move to the next activity but when I click on the text view I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'tv_msisdn'
                                                                                   at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4479)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4443)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

**Code Hear**

```
package com.tela.mobile.home;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.tela.mobile.R;

public class DeviceAlertDetail extends  Activity implements OnClickListener
{
   private TextView tv_number;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.tablerow_overage);

      TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

      tv_number.setOnClickListener(this);

   }
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
      this.startActivity(intent);
   }

}
```

and I am setting onClick for the textView in my layout file as follows

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:text="number"
    android:id="@+id/tv_number"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
       android:onClick="onClick"
       android:clickable="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"

      />
```

Comment: try to remove this line    android:onClick="onClick"

Comment: the error shows the textview id is `tv_msisdn `,not the textview you showed here.

Comment: @FireSun I had changed the name of the textView of posting this sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement `OnClickListener` when you use `android:onClick="onClick"` just let `public void onClick(View view)` as it and remove `implements OnClickListener` from the activity

Your code gonna be like

```
package com.tela.mobile.home;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.tela.mobile.R;

public class DeviceAlertDetail extends  Activity
{
   private TextView tv_number;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.tablerow_overage);

   }
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
      this.startActivity(intent);
   }

}
```

and

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="number"
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        />
```

Comment: I removed implements OnClickListener and now I get an error on                   ` tv_number.setOnClickListener(this);`   a red line under (this )

Comment: delete `TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_number);` and 
 `tv_number.setOnClickListener(this);` too

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misplace reference name.

Just change

```
    tv_number.setOnClickListener(this);
```

with

```
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Your Code Become

```
//Activity

package com.tela.mobile.home;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.tela.mobile.R;

public class DeviceAlertDetail extends  Activity implements OnClickListener
{
   private TextView textView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.tablerow_overage);

      textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

      textView.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   public void onClick(View view)
   {

      Toast.makeText(this,"Code Working Fine Now Remove Comments Of Below",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
      //this.startActivity(intent);
   }

}
```

//.xml becomes

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_column="1"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="1dp"
android:text="number"
android:id="@+id/tv_number"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:maxLines="1"
android:clickable="true"
android:ellipsize="end"

  />
```

Comment: @Context unfortunately I still get exactly the same error

Comment: I copied Your Entire Code... Its works... make above changes and remove attribute android:onClick="onClick" from .xml

Comment: you were right that above code u edited does not give an error the only problem is now when I clicked on the textView nothing happens

Comment: @ Abhishek you were right that above code u edited does not give an error the only problem is now when I clicked on the textView nothing happens

Comment: Try to declare TextView textView; as class member. Not in onCreate. After declearing it as class member initialize it in side onCreate like textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

Comment: Replace android:layout_width="0dp" by android:layout_width="wrap_content" in .xml file TextView tag's Attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't initialize correctly `tv_number`.

You have created an unused local variable `TextView textView`, which may have confused you in thinking that you initialized `tv_number`.

Please replace

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
```

With

```
tv_number = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
```